# How to change div content based on screen size

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, frontend

I would like to change the content of the row divs inside the `indices_container` when the screen becomes small. Currently, on all screen sizes, each row shows the index name, price, 1-day change, and ytd change. I would only like to show the index name and ytd change on small screens.

I am only using Flask and bootstrap to serve my application so I am not even sure if this is even possible without something like react and vue. Can this be done with @media or browser JS?

index.html file:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block body %}
    {% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}
      {% if messages %}
        {% for message in messages %}
          <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible" role="alert">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
            {{message}}
          </div>
        {% endfor %}
      {% endif %}
    {% endwith %}
<div class="indices-container">
  <div class="row">
    {% for index in total_payload.get('indexes').get('meta_data') %}
    <div class="col-sm-2 text-center">
      {% set d = total_payload.get('indexes').get(index) %}
      {{ "{} ${:.2f}".format(index, d['current_price']) }}
      {{ "{:0.2f}% 1-Day".format(d['percent_change']) }}
      {{ "{:0.2f}% YTD".format(d['ytd_percent_change']) }}
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
</div>
<div class="sp500-table-container">
  <div class="table-responsive" id="sp500Table">
    <table class="table table-light table-striped table-sm" id="sp500Table">
      <thead class="thead-light">
        <tr> {% for col in total_payload.get('companies').get('meta_data') %}
          <th>{{ col }}</th>
          {% endfor %}
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody> {% for num, r in enumerate(total_payload.get('companies').get('sp500companies')) %}
        <tr>
          <td>{{ num+1 }}</td>
          <td>{{ r.get('Symbol') }}</td>
          <td>{{ r.get('Security') }}</td>
          <td><a href="{{ r.get('sec_filings') }}" target="_blank">link</a></td>
          <td>{{ r.get('Sector') }}</td>
          <td>{{ r.get('SubSector') }}</td>
          <td>{{ r.get('Headquarters') }}</td>
          <td>{{ r.get('DateFirstAdded') }}</td>
        </tr> {% endfor %}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("p.name-price").css("color", "red");
  });
});
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

style.css file:

```
html {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
body {
    /* padding-bottom: 80px; */
    /* height: 100% */
}
main {
    /* display: flex; */
    /* flex-direction: column; */
    /* flex-grow: 1; */
    padding-bottom: 80px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
footer {
    padding-top: 80px;
}
.indices-container {
    margin: auto;
}
.sp500-table-container {
    height: 70vh;
    width: 100vw;
    overflow: auto;
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 16px;
    margin: auto;
    /* flex: 1; */
    /* margin-bottom: 16px; */
}
```

Comment: "Can this be done with `@media`" - **yes** - that's exactly what it's for. And no, you don't need any JS for that. And VueJS + React etc are not concerned with layout and styling.

Answer (score 1):

This is done with css native [Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries), no additional libraries needed.

It would look something like this:

```
@media (max-width: 400px){
  .indicie-payment { display: none; }
  ...
}
```

BUT

Since you said you are already using Bootstrap, you can use some [utility classes for display](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/utilities/display/) that are already provided by Bootstrap

In your case you would need to wrap some of your items in an element like div or span and use a utility class like `d-sm-none`

So it might look something like this:

```
<div class="indices-container">
  <div class="row">
    {% for index in total_payload.get('indexes').get('meta_data') %}
    <div class="col-sm-2 text-center">
      {% set d = total_payload.get('indexes').get(index) %}
      <span class="d-sm-none">{{ "{} ${:.2f}".format(index, d['current_price']) }}</span>
      <span class="d-sm-none">{{ "{:0.2f}% 1-Day".format(d['percent_change']) }}</span>
      {{ "{:0.2f}% YTD".format(d['ytd_percent_change']) }}
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
</div>
```